# SQL query to group new customers and old customers monthly

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking for a query that can count new and returning customers monthly.

Basically, I have a data of over 2 years of customers who requested for loans, some customers after there the first loan returned after 1, 2, 3... x months. What I want is a query that returns the result in the format below:

```
Month YY  |  New Customers  | Returning Customers
Jan '16   |       6         |        0
Feb '16   |       3         |        0
Mar '16   |       2         |        3
Apr '16   |       4         |        2
```

Some useful columns in my table (Tablename: **Loans**) that I think will be useful here include "**customer_id**", "**date_disbursed**".

Definition of New Customer is a customer_id that appeared for the first time on the table in a given month.
Returning Customer is a customer_id which appears more than once after the first date on the table in subsequent months.

**For example:** If customer_id: "**2231**" first appeared on the table in Jan '16 it should be counted as a New Customer in Jan '16 and if it returns after 2 months which is in Apr '16 he should be counted as a Returning Customer.

Comment: do You need to make it in pure postgre?

Comment: No. Doesn't have to be pure postgres

Comment: the easiest way IMO, would be to make it in PHP... hard to write exact code, as we don't have any real table schema

Comment: I would prefer some examples with any table schema as it will be more complicated explaining my table schema :). A sample SQL query that does that works fine.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) that would be the input for the result you have shown. Ideally as `create table` and `insert` statements

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your query... it did work when I edited to fit my schema. One question is where is it best to insert a JOIN, in the first bracket or second bracket condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this seems to do what you want:

Test setup:

```
create table loans
(
  customer_id integer, 
  date_disbursed date
);

insert into loans
values
( 1, date '2016-01-01'),
( 2, date '2016-01-02'),
( 3, date '2016-01-04'),
( 4, date '2016-01-08'),
( 5, date '2016-01-12'),
( 6, date '2016-01-18'),
( 7, date '2016-02-08'),
( 8, date '2016-02-12'),
( 9, date '2016-03-18'),
(10, date '2016-03-12'),
(11, date '2016-03-18'),
( 3, date '2016-03-04'),
( 4, date '2016-03-08'),
( 5, date '2016-03-12'),
( 5, date '2016-04-12'),
(12, date '2016-04-12'),
( 5, date '2016-05-12'),
( 6, date '2016-05-18');
```

Query:

```
select to_char(date_disbursed, 'yyyy-mm') as month,
       count(*) filter (where new_customer) as new_customers,
       count(*) filter (where recurring_customer) as returning_customers
from (       
  select customer_id,
         date_disbursed, 
         date_disbursed = min(date_disbursed) over w as new_customer,
         date_disbursed > min(date_disbursed) over w as recurring_customer
  from loans
  window w as (partition by customer_id)
) t
group by to_char(date_disbursed, 'yyyy-mm')
order by to_char(date_disbursed, 'yyyy-mm');
```

returns

```
month   | new_customers | returning_customers
--------+---------------+--------------------
2016-01 |             6 |                   0
2016-02 |             2 |                   0
2016-03 |             3 |                   3
2016-04 |             1 |                   1
2016-05 |             0 |                   2
```